# Binary Search Tree , need help to figure out

Tags: perl, binary-search-tree

```
{
    package Node;
    sub new{
        my ($class, $data) = @_;
        return bless $data, shift;
    }
}

{
    package BinarySearchTree;   
    sub new{
        my ($class, $val) = @_;
        return bless Node->new({val => $val}), $class
    }

    sub right{
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{right}
    }

    sub data{
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->{val}
    }

    sub insert{
        my ($self, $val) = @_;
        if ($val > $self->{val}){
            $self->{right} = Node->new({val => $val})
        }elsif($val < $self->{val}){
            $self->{left} = Node->new({val => $val})
        }
    }
}

1;
```

When i use this package

```
my $t = BinarySearchTree->new(5);
$t->insert(6);
print $t->right->data;
```

He gave me error
Can locate method 'data' via package 'Node', if i  move method data to Node, they work fine. 
How can i fix it , or rewrite this code .

Comment: `$self->{right} = Node->new({val => $val})` looks like the reason.

Comment: To flesh out what @TLP wrote, you are storing `Node` objects in your tree, then you are retrieving a `Node` object and calling the `data` method on it.  So, putting the `data` method in the `Node` class seems like the correct solution.  Is there a reason you believe it should be in the tree class?

Comment: only one reason , i can't pass the unit tests, 'Can't locate object method "data" via package "BinarySearchTree".  The unit tests https://github.com/exercism/xperl5/blob/master/binary-search-tree/binary_search_tree.t

Comment: You have a design problem.  Trees are composed of nodes, but it is the nodes which contain all of the information.  You are attaching attributes to the tree (right,data) which belong in the node.  If the API requires that the tree object act like a node (i.e. return attributes associated with the root node), then you either need to delegate to the root node or dispense completely with the tree object and just use nodes.

Comment: In the Tree class's constructor you create a Node object, then bless it as a Tree object.  Why?

Comment: Diab Jerius, thanks . i only needed a one class